# How to skip hibernation mode and boot into windows directly?

Tags: windows-7, windows, hibernate

I did a hibernate last time and now I got into boot loop in my laptop. I see the bios screen and it restarts again. 
I want to know if I can get into command line using a bootable windows setup and delete the hibersys file and get into normal Windows boot.

Comment: It doesn't really sound like a hibernation issue, but if you have a Windows 7 install DVD you can boot to it and get to a command line.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried this with Windows 7, but in earlier versions (Windows XP) pressing F8 allows the resume process to be interrupted and gives the option to delete the hibernation image.

A hard reboot during resume should also work (it makes Windows think the boot or resume failed).

Comment: I cant see the Windows logo itself. it restarts right after config bios screen.

Answer (score 0):

You can press the <kbd>Space</kbd> key to skip hibernation. For an unknwn reason on my old laptop, I got the old XP style resume progressbar on Win7 and there it was written that <kbd>Space</kbd> key should skip it. So try it out.